# Does neuroticism decline with age?

Tags: neuroticism

Do we know so far whether neuroticism declines with age?

I found contradictory sources about the evolution of neuroticism across the life span.

- [Barlow et al. (2014) "The origins of neuroticism"](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1745691614544528)

> That is, after emerging in childhood, neuroticism remains relatively stable before showing gradual age-related decreases that continue into old age (Eaton, Krueger, & Oltmanns, 2011; Roberts & Mroczeck, 2008; Roberts, Walton, & Viechtbauer, 2006)

- [Donnellan & Lucas (2008) "Age Differences in the Big Five Across the Life Span"](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0012897)

> The one exception was that Neuroticism was slightly negatively associated with age in the BHPS [British Household Panel Study] and slightly positively associated with age in the GSEOP [German Socio-Economic Panel Study].

- [Roberts et al. (2006) Patterns of Mean-Level Change in Personality Traits Across the Life Course](https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.132.1.1)

There is also this graph displaying the evolution of emotional stability across the life span

[image]

Comment: Given the "slightly" adjective used in the last paper (twice), the effect size is probably small, so that noise factors like questionnaire translation or even cultural factors may be what's detected.